# How do I get the program to display the sum of the values divisible by 5, versus just the values themselves?

Tags: java, loops, methods

The program asks that a method be created. The method takes two parameters: start and end, both integers. The method must sum all of the numbers between start and end that are divisible by 5. For example, if start is 1 and end is 30, the answer must be 105, since 5 + 10 + 15 + 20 + 25 + 30 = 105 are the numbers that are divisible by 5 and belong to the range of 1 and 5.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Divisor{

  public static void main(String[] args){

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Enter a start: ");
    int start = input.nextInt();

    System.out.print("Enter an end: ");
    int end = input.nextInt();

    int result6 = sumDivisor(start, end); 
    System.out.println(result6);

}

 public static int sumDivisor (int start, int end){
    int value = end;
    for(int i = 5;i <= end;i = i + 5){
      value = i;
      System.out.print(i + " ");      
    }
    return value;
  }
 }
```

Comment: how's the homework coming along?

Comment: You can create another int that all the values of the number are added to.

Comment: I'm doing practice problems to prepare for an exam, and it's going well, thank you, donfede. This has become one of those problems where I blank, though the answer is probably right under my nose.

Comment: Just as I suspected, the answer was right underneath my nose. Thank you for your help, gangqinlaohu! Turns out, value had to be set to 0, as Femaref suggested, and the counter had to be added to value to create the new value. The println was also unnecessary, and an over-complication by my part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also have to take into account the situation where your start argument is not divisible by 5:

```
public static int sumDivisor (int start, int end){
int value = 0;
    while (start % 5 != 0) {            
        start++;
    }
for(int i = start;i <= end;i += 5){
  value += i;    
}
return value;
```

}

Comment: Would you mind spelling out to me what exactly that while loop does? I am not very familiar with remainder(%), though I know it has an equivalence to the for loop I did use. Thank you very much, user2098232!

Comment: The while loop increases the start value until it's divisible by 5 (remainder of the division start by 5 equals 0). For example: if the start value would be 3, without the while loop, the for loop would just icrease i by 5 and add it to value and the function would return the sum 3, 8 , 13, 18 ... The while loop in this situation first icreases start = 3 until start = 5, that is divisible by 5 and then it gets to the for loop.

Comment: That makes great sense! Thank you again, user2098232!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of returning the last number, start it at `0` and add every number fulfilling your condition to it.

Comment: Thank you very much for your input, Femaref! I believe I'm doing it incorrectly. By setting value equal to 0, and within the for loop, setting value += to i, I continue to receive a listing of the numbers versus the value of the sum. I realize it must also be in part to my println, but I am indeed... stuck.